# Mixing syscall write with printf on linux

Tags: c, linux, assembly, printf, x86-64

I was doing some test in assembly calling c functions and I get what I think es a strange behavior when using ansi escape codes and calling a c function that uses printf.

This is the assembly part:

```
section .data               

    red db 27,"[31;1m",0
    redlen equ $ - red

    cyan db 27,"[36;1m",0
    cyanlen equ $ - cyan

    colorReset db 27,"[0m",0
    colorResetLen equ $ - colorReset

section .text

extern printLetter
extern letter

global main

main:
        mov  BYTE [letter], 'H'
        call ansiSetRed
        call printLetter
        mov  BYTE [letter], 'e'
        call ansiSetCyan
        call printLetter
        mov  BYTE [letter], 'l'
        call ansiReset
        call printLetter
        mov  BYTE [letter], 'l'
        call ansiSetRed
        call printLetter
        mov  BYTE [letter], 'o'
        call ansiSetCyan
        call printLetter
        mov  BYTE [letter], '!'
        call ansiReset
        call printLetter
        mov  BYTE [letter], 10
        call printLetter

        ret

ansiSetRed:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, red
        mov rdx, redlen
        syscall
        ret

ansiSetCyan:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, cyan
        mov rdx, cyanlen
        syscall
        ret

ansiReset:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, colorReset
        mov rdx, colorResetLen
        syscall
        ret
```

Looks long but all that i does is define some strings with ansi codes at the beginning, one to set foreground color to red, one for cyan and one to reset the colors.

Then I have functions that print this ansi strings using syscall write.

The main function is just supposed to print "Hello!" alternating the color of each letter, by first calling an assembly function that prints the corresponding ansi string, and then calling an extern c function that prints a character that is stored in a global variable.

Here the c part:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char letter;

void printLetter(void) {

    printf("%c", letter);

}
```

When I run it, the Message "Hello!" is displayed all white like if the assembly part was not printing the ansi codes

[image]

but if I change the c part to just print a new line after each character:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char letter;

void printLetter(void) {

    printf("%c\n", letter);

}
```

Then the letters show one of each color as I expected at the beginning.

[image]

What can be the cause of this behavior?

Comment: Useful debugging tools for this: `strace` to trace system calls, `ltrace` to trace library function calls.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because stdio (the C standard I/O package) uses line buffering for stdout if stdout goes to a terminal. That means that data you write is not immediately sent to the terminal but rather buffered until a whole line is available. What you observe in your first program (hello on a line) is that no character of `Hello` is actually written until you call `printLetter` with a line feed, causing the buffer for stdout to be flushed to the terminal.

I see the following approaches to solve your problem (any single of them does the trick, but use only one approach):

- edit `ansiSetRed` etc. to call `fwrite` instead of directly executing a `write` system call. This should make buffering work as expected.
- call `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` to turn off buffering before writing any data.
- write to `stderr` instead of `stdout` as `stderr` is unbuffered
- execute `fflush(stdout)` after each `printf` to manually flush `stdout`.
- Rewrite `printLetter` to use the system call `write` instead of `printf`.

Comment: More in general, never mix IO calls to functions at different "levels" of the software stack but working on the same device unless you take care to properly synchronize them (flush buffers & co.).

Comment: @MatteoItalia Which all my suggestions do (disabling buffering is documented in POSIX as behaving as if `fflush` was executed after every write if I recall correctly).

Comment: of course, in facts I upvoted your answer =) I was just making more explicit the general point.